# CKEdtior adding extra paragraphs every time I save the document

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

I'm using CKEditor in Typo3, having a yaml-file with the configuration for it.

Every time I save the document, CKEditor adds extra paragraphs and converts `<br />`'s to `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

So this

```
<p>my paragraph</p>
<p>my paragraph with<br />a newline</p>
```

becomes this:

```
<p>my paragraph</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>my paragraph with</p>
<p>a newline</p>
```

I tried to use `autoParagraph: false` (which is deprecated and thus didn't work) and `enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` // `shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR`

Didn't help...

Any ideas?

That's what my yaml-file looks like:

```
# Load default processing options
imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }
# Konfiguration
editor:

  externalPlugins:
    typo3link: { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Plugins/typo3link.js", route: "rteckeditor_wizard_browse_links" }

  config:
  # height: 70 (2 Zeilen) +20 pro weitere jede Zeile
    height: 130
    width: "auto"
    fillEmtpyBlocks: false
    ignoreEmptyParagraph: false
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR

    # Formatauswahl
    format_tags: "h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;p"

    # Stylesheet
    contentsCss: "EXT:upd_rte_extension/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css"

    # Styleauswahl
    stylesSet:
    # Blockstile
      - { name: "Disclaimer", element: "p", attributes: { 'class': 'disclaimer' } }
      - { name: "Wichtig", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'important' } }

    # Buttons
      - { name: "Wow-Button", element: "a", attributes: { 'class': 'wow-button' } }

    toolbar:
    - { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] }
    - { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] }
    - { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format' ] }
    - { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }
    - '/'
    - { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] }
    - { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Scayt' ] }
    - { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] }
    - { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] }
    - { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] }
    - { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source' ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with flux and the RTE. It's already fixed on the dev branch, but if you need the master (as we do) you have to apply this fix: https://github.com/dacostafilipe/flux/commit/e1e3b5d9f48b7c45bbae1494e30f7838c24cedeb

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here in 8.7.13 (and current 9 as well). But none of the suggestions work for me!? No flux or dce in use. Just a plugin using `pi_flexform` with a flexform like this:

```
<settings.bookingConfirmationEmailBody>
    <config>
        <type>text</type>
        <rows>5</rows>
        <cols>30</cols>
        <eval>trim,required</eval>
        <enableRichtext>1</enableRichtext>
        <richtextConfiguration>exhibitors_email</richtextConfiguration>
    </config>
</settings.bookingConfirmationEmailBody>
```

I figured out, that on direction "from rte to db", eveything is stored correctly. But "from db to rte", newlines and `<br>` are converted to `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, which multiplies each time i save. Already spent hours on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in a previous project. 
In my case it was a bug in FLUX… I did this:

Flux/Classe/Form/Field/Text.php:61 added
`$configuration[‘enableRichtext’] = true;
$configuration[‘richtextConfiguration’] = ‘full’;

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.

*Note: the following applies for Typo3 8.7.7 and flux 8.2.1, didn't test it on other installations.*

The problem was, that I didn't use the latest Flux-Version from Github. In my case, downloading and replacing of the following file solved the problem (if you're not running the latest version):

```
flux/Classes/Field/Text.php
```

Add the custom RTE to the GLOBALS of your extension (usually, that'd be your flux-template extension)

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['custom_rte'] = 'fileadmin/templates/mysite/css/custom_rte.yaml';
```

Then, in the Page TSConfig:

```
RTE.default.preset = custom_rte
plugin.tx_flux.settings.flexform.richtextConfiguration = custom_rte
```

The first line is for the overall usage of the custom RTE-Config
The second line tells flux to use the custom RTE-config as well (that's the important one).

Hope this helps somebody...